# Coldfusion and mySQL 5.6.41 returning datetime errors due to extracted format 2021-02-07T15:32:54

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I am getting errors in Mac OS Coldfusion 2016 reading a mySQL 5.6.41 database with field type of datetime. A simple cfquery select * with cfdump produces java class error "java.time.LocalDateTime" on the datetime fields while producing expected data output in all other fields.
Attempting to output the field value as text, it returns the date/time with a T separator '2021-02-07T15:32:54' (which could be parsed).
But no ColdFusion date/time functions work due to this format.
The data was exported from mySQL 5.6.19 via SQL export using Sequel Pro and imported into the new 5.6.41 instance. All code runs fine on the previous server. I have attempted using the installed mySQL 5 datasource in ColdFusion and a JDBC driver. Both connect fine, but produce same DATETIME format.
Changing the field type to DATE or TIMESTAMP allows the CFDUMP to display without error in the DATETIME fields (obviously minus TIME if DATE).
There is a large amount of labor/overhead involved to not be able to keep DATETIME working as built (plus I believe its the correct field type). I have run out of google options and hoping someone can explain the difference and reason and solution the Coldfusion 2016 will not query data in the same manner as similar code/server.

Comment: What are the column types in your database? How does your code look like? Are you dumping the raw cfquery `name="..."` variable? Stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: I can do a select of just the DATETIME columns and same error.msg.    
<cfquery name="FIND_QRY" datasource="myDataSource" maxrows=1> SELECT * FROM ORDER_UPDATES WHERE NAME = '#variables.NAME#' </cfquery> and dumping cfdump var="#FIND_QRY#">  => and the message inside the cfdump containing the DATETIME field => object of java.time.LocalDateTime
Class Name  java.time.LocalDateTime
Methods  
Method  Return Type
adjustInto(java.time.temporal.Temporal)  java.time.temporal.Temporal
atOffset(java.time.ZoneOffset)  java.time.OffsetDateTime
atZone(java.time.ZoneId)  java.time.ZonedDateTime
....

Comment: Sounds like the JDBC driver is trying to convert a field that is not the expected type (datetime) and thus failing at conversion. What JDBC driver are you using? You also mentioned the datetime field being ISO 8601 on output, which is not something CF usually outputs (CF uses ODBC timestamp literal `{ts '2021-02-07 15:32:54'}`). Maybe your export changed the datetime format, which still works with MySQL, but is not accepted by JDBC. Create a new table with a clean datetime column and try selecting it. Does it still happen?

Comment: new table, 2 fields, id and testDate (DATETIME). INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE
(id,testdate)values  (1,#createodbcdatetime(now())#) - inserts fine - read get same error. tried the shipped sql5 driver and current jdbc 8.0.23 for datasources

Comment: Hi @Torsten. I am having the same problem here after updating CF Server to 2021. Even if the dates in the mySQL database are in '2022-01-20 17:23:00' when I read the database with CFQUERY, the date is retrieved as '2022-01-20T17:23:00'. Because of the 'T' the IsDate() function doesn't recognize this value as a valid date. Did you manage to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I solved this was to remove `mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar` and replace it with an older version - `mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar` in my case. So, the problem comes from the mySQL connector.

Comment: Suposedly the v8.0.22 jar works (behavior was changed in 8.0.23) and there is also mention of a patch for those on CF 2021 in this bug report, though I haven't tried it myself https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-4211276